# How to use Clients.Caller and Clients.Others in SignalR when doing DI in a Controller (ASP.NET Core)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I am using SignalR with ASP.NET Core:

```cs
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
}
```

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext;

    public AController(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }
}
```

I found out that I can only use the properties `Clients.Caller` and `Clients.Others`

```cs
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
        public void Test()
        {
            Clients.Caller.SendAsync("aMethod");
            Clients.Others.SendAsync("aMethod");
        }
}
```

While with `IHubContext<NotificationHub>` I only have access to:

```cs
_hubContext.Clients.All
```

Is there any way I can get access to `Clients.Caller` and `Clients.Others` properties outsite of the Hub?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your SignalR client communicates only with the hub, thus you never have a "Caller" in a controller, only in the hub.

The HubContext you pass to the controller can be used to send messages back to any registered connections, either by broadcasting to all or to a selected group of connection ids.

So if you can match the controller user to the connection id, you can have the equivalent to `Clients.Caller` by issuing a `Clients.Client("connection-id")`, and a `Clients.Others` by using `Clients.AllExcept(...)` or similar.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. 
For the sake of curiosity, I will check the code behind `Clients.Caller` and `Clients.Others `

Answer (score -3):

It makes no sense at all that MS would provide and IHuBContext with no CallingClinet.

There is always a Calling client, and the only way to get it is through dependency injection.
Shame on you MS.